# VS Code search and replace - regular expression

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to remove quotation marks in VC Code using regular expressions?

Having this():

```
"Hello world"
```

Regular:

```
[^"]
```

Print

```
 $0
```

Output - still:

```
"Hello world"
```

Comment: Why can't you just find `"` and replace with nothing?  Some other restrictions in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you write just results in matching every non double-quote character as an individual match result. `$0` represents the entire matched text, which for each matched character, is just that matched character.

To get *rid* of double-quote characters, you don't even need regex matching (as you were told in the comments). Turn off regex mode and just match the double-quote character, then leave the replacement field blank and click the button to replace all matches.